# creating custom namespaces in rss

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, rss

I wish to create some custom namespaces in my rss feed.
The problem is that I have the rss feed working, but the custom namespace data does not show up. I have got it to this far but if anyone could assist in showing how to get this to work properly ( if at all) it would be greatly appreciated.
below is the code i am using to achieve this to this point.
the reason for custom naming is that I am unable to attach the data to anything else that has been already approved.

```
<?
//Configure the Basic information

$chan_title = "sponsor";
$chan_desc = "some sponsor data.";
$chan_link = "http://pandafc.elementfx.com/panda_app_page.php";
//$image_url = "logo.gif";

//connect to the Database

include 'connect.php';

$query = "SELECT sp_ID, sp_name, sp_about, sp_website FROM sponsors ORDER BY sp_ID DESC LIMIT 25";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {
    die("No records");
}


//Build the XML data

$items = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $item_id = $row["sp_ID"];
    $item_title = $row["sp_name"];
    $item_link = $row["sp_about"];
    $item_desc = $row["sp_website"];
    $items .= <<<ITEM
        <item>
            <title>$item_id</title>
            <sponsor:sponsor>$item_title</sponsor:sponsor>
            <sponsor:about>$item_link</sponsor:about>
            <sponsor:Website>$item_desc</sponsor:Website>
        </item>

ITEM;
}

$content = <<<CONTENT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:sponsor="http://pandafc.elementfx.com/nssponsor.xhtml" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
        <channel>
                <title>$chan_title</title>
                <link>$chan_link</link>
                <description>$chan_desc</description>
$items
<atom:link href="http://pandafc.elementfx.com/rssfeed1.php" />
        </channel>
</rss>

CONTENT;

//print results on screen

header("Content-type: application/rss+xml");
print $content;
 ?>
```

hopefully this can be achieved and others may also find this useful

Comment: what means 'does not show up' ?

Comment: the results do not show up on an rss reader

Comment: How should the rss reader knowing about your extensions? the reader will only show what is standardized by RSS

Comment: that's what i am hoping i can change or modify. but i am trying to do this to use the rss feed specifically for a phone app hopefully.

Comment: You need to modify the reader in order show that extensions

Comment: do you or anyone else know how to modify the reader to achieve this.

Comment: That's a quite complex task. Read and understand the sourcecode of the RSS reader of your choice and learn how to modify it

Comment: thanks. ill have to check that out then